# how to split strings to characters with multiple delimiters using str split

Tags: r, string

i have my input something like this,

```
x
  nct_id                            drug
1 NCT100            paracetomol+velacade
2 NCT123                      bortezomib
3 NCT145                        velacade
4 NCT645           velacade,dexamethaone
5 NCT768             bortezomib||velacde
6 NCT890 velacade\\bortezomib\\ethonisde
```

i used the following code to split column 2 based on various delimiters at once

```
 y2<-strsplit(x[,2],split="[||,,,\\,+]")
> y2
[[1]]
[1] "paracetomol" "velacade" 

[[2]]
[1] "bortezomib"

[[3]]
[1] "velacade"

[[4]]
[1] "velacade"     "dexamethaone"

[[5]]
[1] "bortezomib" ""           "velacde"   

[[6]]
[1] "velacade"   "bortezomib" "ethonisde"
```

i am getting an extra space or character at 5 so how to avoid it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also fix this by modifying your regular expression. I added a second backslash to escape the first backslash and to directly address you problem, added a "+" to tell the regex engine to allow for repetition of as many of the characters in the character class "[\|,+]" as appear next to one another.

Note that I wrapped the drug variable in `as.character` because it is a factor variable due the fact that `read.table` converts character strings to factors by default.

```
strsplit(as.character(df$drug), split="[\\|,+]+")
[[1]]
[1] "paracetomol" "velacade"   

[[2]]
[1] "bortezomib"

[[3]]
[1] "velacade"

[[4]]
[1] "velacade"     "dexamethaone"

[[5]]
[1] "bortezomib" "velacde"   

[[6]]
[1] "velacade"   "bortezomib" "ethonisde"
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="nct_id  drug
1 NCT100            paracetomol+velacade
2 NCT123                      bortezomib
3 NCT145                        velacade
4 NCT645           velacade,dexamethaone
5 NCT768             bortezomib||velacde
6 NCT890 velacade\\bortezomib\\ethonisde")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x$drug, "[A-Za-z]+")
#[[1]]
#[1] "paracetomol" "velacade"   

#[[2]]
#[1] "bortezomib"

#[[3]]
#[1] "velacade"

#[[4]]
#[1] "velacade"     "dexamethaone"

#[[5]]
#[1] "bortezomib" "velacde"   

#[[6]]
#[1] "velacade"   "bortezomib" "ethonisde"
```